# Can a Syrian refugee from the UK who has indefinite leave to remain apply for US visa if he marries a US citizen?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom

I'm an an American citizen. My fiancé lives in England and is a refugee from Syria. He has his indefinite leave to remain in the UK. He has lived there 6+ years. We want to be married next year. I am going to apply for the marriage visitor visa and get married, stay for a while and then come back to the states. Will I be able to bring him here on a marriage visa since we will already be married?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that he is a Syrian national and does not have dual nationality with a non-banned country, he cannot currently get a US visa due to the "Muslim ban". However, I expect the "Muslim ban" to be revoked right after Biden takes office. By the time you guys have married and the I-130 is approved (the I-130 takes a few months at least), there should be no problem with him getting a visa.